# Split string IF delimiter is found

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the following data frame,

```
cols = ['Id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']
vals = [('1A','Not his side|:|This side', 'This side', 'Not this either|:|but this'),  
        ('1B','Keep this', 'This one|:|keep this', 'remove|:|keep that')]

dd1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(vals, cols)

#+---+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
#|Id |col1                    |col2                |col3                      |
#+---+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
#|1A |Not his side|:|This side|This side           |Not this either|:|but this|
#|1B |Keep this               |This one|:|keep this|remove|:|keep that        |
#+---+------------------------+--------------------+--------------------------+
```

What I need to do is to split the strings at `|:|` and keep the second word. However, If the string does not contain the delimiter (`|:|`), then I get `null`,
i.e.:

```
users1 = [F.split(F.col(x), "\\|:\\|").alias(x) for x in cols]
dd1.select(*users1).show()

#+---------+---------+---------+
#|     col1|     col2|     col3|
#+---------+---------+---------+
#|This side|     null| but this|
#|     null|keep this|keep that|
#+---------+---------+---------+
```

The result I'm looking for is:

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+
|Id |col1     |col2     |col3     |
+---+---------+---------+---------+
|1A |This side|This side|but this |
|1B |Keep this|keep this|keep that|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: You can also use regex `regexp_replace(col(c), "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\\|:\\|" , "")` if you only have texts, numbers and spaces before the delimiter

Comment: @philantrovert thanks. However, that would be less efficient I guess right?

Comment: It's not a very complex regex but compared to other string based answers, possibly yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `when` and `otherwise` and check if the string contains `"|:|"`. It can be done as follows:

```
cols = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

users1 = [F.when(F.col(x).contains("|:|"), F.split(F.col(x), "\\|:\\|")[1]).otherwise(F.col(x)).alias(x) for x in cols]
dd1.select(F.col('Id'), *users1)
```

Here the `cols` only include the columns that you want to split. The final `select` will include the `Id` column as well.

Comment: @Sotos: No problems, happy to help. I saw you asked for the Id column, you can see above in the answer how to select it with the rest.

Comment: So for multiple columns it would be something like `df.select(F.col('cdatetime'), F.col('username'), F.col('eventid'), *users1)`?

Comment: @Sotos: Yes, you can do that. Or you can include them in the `cols` variable, in that case there will be some extra computations but the code could look cleaner. If you have multiple columns to keep then you could create a new list with those and unpack it in the same way as `users1`.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `when` and `size` inbuilt functions as

```
users1 = [F.when(F.size(F.split(F.col(x), "\\|:\\|")) > 1, F.split(F.col(x), "\\|:\\|")[1]).otherwise(F.col(x)).alias(x) for x in cols]
dd1.select(*users1).show()
```

which should give you

```
+---+---------+---------+---------+
| Id|     col1|     col2|     col3|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
| 1A|This side|This side| but this|
| 1B|Keep this|keep this|keep that|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
```

You can modify the answer so that you can use `split` function only once.

I hope the answer is helpful and should be a good hint on how to proceed.

Comment: This is the concept I was going for but was missing something and couldn't quite get there. Thank you @Ramesh

Comment: It does not give me the `Id`. Where are you selecting it?

Comment: Id is present in your `cols = ['Id', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3']` so it should just come as its in users1 function

Comment: Ahh, ok. I see. Wouldn't that make the operation heavier though? Considering that in my real set I will have 3 `Id`-style columns that I would want to keep

Comment: You can just exclude it from the cols and then use the id columns in select for that case

Answer (score 1):

The selection you defined in your questions does not yield the result you mentioned. I think you forgot to select the element from the array ;)

```
users1 = [F.split(F.col(x), "\\|:\\|").alias(x) for x in cols]
dd1.select(*users1).show()
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  Id|                col1|                col2|                col3|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|[1A]|[Not his side, Th...|         [This side]|[Not this either,...|
|[1B]|         [Keep this]|[This one, keep t...| [remove, keep that]|
+----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

To achieve what you want, you simply need to select the last element of the array. You can use the size function for this:

```
users2 = [F.col(x).getItem(F.size(F.col(x))-1).alias(x) for x in cols]
dd1.select(*users1).select(*users2).show()
+---+---------+---------+---------+
| Id|     col1|     col2|     col3|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
| 1A|This side|This side| but this|
| 1B|Keep this|keep this|keep that|
+---+---------+---------+---------+
```